# PowerShell Service - Output Reading Incorrect

Tags: powershell, logging, service, output

Trying to write a PowerShell script that does the following:

1. Look for service existence
2. If found, check service status
3. Report service status
4. If service status is not running start service
5. Report service status

***Issue:*** If I run the script once, the final service status will say running but the message printed before it will be that it couldn't start the service. If I run the script again, it'll flip flop and say that the service has been started, but final status is stopped.

**Current Code:**

```
# Setting variables

$date = Get-Date # setting date
$LogFile = "$env:UserProfile\Desktop\Log.txt" # setting log file - change as needed
$ServiceName = "Spooler" # setting service name - change as needed
$arrService = Get-Service -Name $ServiceName
$arrServiceCheck = Get-Service -Name $ServiceName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable NoService


<# =============== DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING BELOW THIS POINT =============== #>

# Creating functions for re-use throughout script

function CurrentServiceStatus {
    Write-Output "Status of '$ServiceName' service:" | Out-File $LogFile -append
    Get-Service $ServiceName | Select Name,DisplayName,Status | Format-List | Out-File $LogFile -append
}

# Starting script operation

Write-Output "=========================================================================" | Out-File $LogFile
Write-Output "    Starting '$ServiceName' Service Monitor Script on $date" | Out-File $LogFile -append
Write-Output "=========================================================================" | Out-File $LogFile -append
Write-Output " " | Out-File $LogFile -append

# Looking for service. If service was found, checking it's status. If status is not running, starting the service.

if ($arrServiceCheck){
    Write-Output "'$ServiceName' service found on $env:ComputerName..." | Out-File $LogFile -append
    Write-Output " " | Out-File $LogFile -append

    ServiceStatus

    if ($arrService.Status -ne "Running"){
        Start-Service $ServiceName | Out-File $LogFile -append
    }

    if ($arrService.Status -eq "Running"){
        Write-Output "$date - '$ServiceName' started..." | Out-File $LogFile -append
        Write-Output " " | Out-File $LogFile -append
        ServiceStatus
    }
    else{
        Write-Output "Error: '$ServiceName' service could not be started..." | Out-File $LogFile -append
        Write-Output " " | Out-File $LogFile -append
        ServiceStatus
    }
}

# If service was not found, making note of it to log file

if ($NoService){
    Write-Output " " | Out-File $LogFile -append
Write-Output $NoService[0].exception.message | Out-File $LogFile -append
    Write-Output " " | Out-File $LogFile -append
}

# Completing running of script

Write-Output "=========================================================================" | Out-File $LogFile -append
Write-Output "    Finished '$ServiceName' Service Monitor Script on $date" | Out-File $LogFile -append
Write-Output "=========================================================================" | Out-File $LogFile -append
Write-Output " " | Out-File $LogFile -append
Write-Output " " | Out-File $LogFile -append
```

**Here is my output...**

*Run 1:*

```
=========================================================================
    Starting 'Spooler' Service Monitor Script on 01/13/2016 12:06:49
=========================================================================

'Spooler' service found on MW762OXI5K7M8D...

Current status of 'Spooler' service:


Name        : Spooler
DisplayName : Print Spooler
Status      : Stopped



01/13/2016 12:06:49 - 'Spooler' started...

Final status of 'Spooler' service:


Name        : Spooler
DisplayName : Print Spooler
Status      : Stopped



=========================================================================
    Finished 'Spooler' Service Monitor Script on 01/13/2016 12:06:49
=========================================================================
```

*Run 2:*

```
=========================================================================
    Starting 'Spooler' Service Monitor Script on 01/13/2016 12:15:58
=========================================================================

'Spooler' service found on MW762OXI5K7M8D...

Current status of 'Spooler' service:


Name        : Spooler
DisplayName : Print Spooler
Status      : Stopped



'Spooler' service could not be started...

Final status of 'Spooler' service:


Name        : Spooler
DisplayName : Print Spooler
Status      : Running



=========================================================================
    Finished 'Spooler' Service Monitor Script on 01/13/2016 12:15:58
=========================================================================
```

**==========================================**

**Here is the corrected code:**

```
# Setting variables

$date = Get-Date # setting date
$LogFile = "$env:UserProfile\Desktop\NXLogMonitor\Logging\NXLogMonitor.txt"    # setting log file - change as needed
$ServiceName = "Spooler" # setting service name - change as needed
$arrService = Get-Service -Name $ServiceName
$arrServiceCheck = Get-Service -Name $ServiceName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable NoService


<# =============== DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING BELOW THIS POINT =============== #>

# Creating functions for re-use throughout script

function ServiceStatus {
    Write-Output "Status of '$ServiceName' service:" | Out-File $LogFile -append
    Get-Service $ServiceName | Select Name,DisplayName,Status | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-File $LogFile -append
}

# Starting script operation

Write-Output "=========================================================================" | Out-File $LogFile
Write-Output "    Starting '$ServiceName' Service Monitor Script on $date" | Out-File $LogFile -append
Write-Output "=========================================================================" | Out-File $LogFile -append
Write-Output " " | Out-File $LogFile -append

# Looking for service. If service was found, checking it's status. If status is not running, starting the service.

if ($arrServiceCheck){
    Write-Output "'$ServiceName' service found on $env:ComputerName..." | Out-File $LogFile -append
    Write-Output " " | Out-File $LogFile -append

    if ($arrService.Status -eq "Running"){
        Write-Output "'$ServiceName' is already started..." | Out-File $LogFile -append
        Write-Output " " | Out-File $LogFile -append
        ServiceStatus
    }

    if ($arrService.Status -ne "Running"){
        Write-Output "'$ServiceName' service is not started..." | Out-File $LogFile -append
        Write-Output " " | Out-File $LogFile -append

        ServiceStatus

        $arrService = Start-Service $ServiceName -PassThru
        if ($arrService.Status -eq "Running"){
            Write-Output "$date - '$ServiceName' service started..." | Out-File $LogFile -append
            Write-Output " " | Out-File $LogFile -append
            ServiceStatus
        }
        elseif ($arrService.Status -ne "Running"){
            Write-Output "Error: '$ServiceName' service could not be started..." | Out-File $LogFile -append
            Write-Output " " | Out-File $LogFile -append
            ServiceStatus
        }
    }
}

# If service was not found, making note of it to log file

if ($NoService){
    Write-Output " " | Out-File $LogFile -append
Write-Output $NoService[0].exception.message | Out-File $LogFile -append
    Write-Output " " | Out-File $LogFile -append
}

# Completing running of script

Write-Output "=========================================================================" | Out-File $LogFile -append
Write-Output "    Finished '$ServiceName' Service Monitor Script on $date" | Out-File $LogFile -append
Write-Output "=========================================================================" | Out-File $LogFile -append
Write-Output " " | Out-File $LogFile -append
Write-Output " " | Out-File $LogFile -append
```

**Here is the output of the corrected code:**

```
=========================================================================
    Starting 'Spooler' Service Monitor Script on 01/13/2016 13:53:08
=========================================================================

'Spooler' service found on MW762OXI5K7M8D...

'Spooler' is already started...

Status of 'Spooler' service:

Name    DisplayName    Status
----    -----------    ------
Spooler Print Spooler Running


=========================================================================
    Finished 'Spooler' Service Monitor Script on 01/13/2016 13:53:08
=========================================================================
```

Comment: `$arrService.Status` won't change in between your different if/else statements, it remains the same throughout the script. Run `Get-Service` again instead of inspecting and "old" variable value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a good look at what you do at the beginning:

```
$arrService = Get-Service -Name $ServiceName
```

`$arrService.Status` now reflects the status of the service *before* you start doing anything - **let us imagine that the status is `Stopped`**

Then, later in your script:

```
if ($arrService.Status -ne "Running"){
    Start-Service $ServiceName | Out-File $LogFile -append
}
```

This part works as expected - the service wasn't running when you launched the script, and so it'll be started now, great!

Then comes the problematic part of your script:

```
if ($arrService.Status -eq "Running"){
       Write-Output "$date - '$ServiceName' started..." | Out-File $LogFile -append
       Write-Output " " | Out-File $LogFile -append
       FinalServiceStatus
}
else{
    Write-Output "Error: '$ServiceName' service could not be started..." | Out-File $LogFile -append
    Write-Output " " | Out-File $LogFile -append
    FinalServiceStatus
}
```

Since `$arrService.Status` *still* has the exact same value as before (even though the service itself may now have changed its status to `Running`), the `else` block is executed, regardless of whether or not the service was successfully started.

---

You need to call `Get-Service` *again* to get the new value of the service, or (my personal favourite) use `Start-Service -PassThru` to "update" the `$arrService` variable:

```
if($arrService.Status -ne 'Running')
{
    $arrService = Start-Service $ServiceName -PassThru
}

if($arrService.Status -eq 'Running')
{
    "Service is running" # although we don't know whether it was just started or already had been 
}
else
{
    "Service not running, starting must have failed"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that, @Mathias. I got it working with your assistance. Totally missed that, but definitely understand how that could be a problem. The -passthru switch is a nice touch too :).

Now if I could just get the formatting correct...

Comment: That's a different question (feel free to ask a new one). Hint: Don't use `Format-List`, it adds the undesired newlines.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for the assistance on solving the biggest issue @Mathias.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, per Mathias' suggestion, here is what my code ended up looking like (as far as the logic goes):

```
if ($arrServiceCheck){
    Write-Output "'$ServiceName' service found on $env:ComputerName..." | Out-File $LogFile -append
    Write-Output " " | Out-File $LogFile -append

    if ($arrService.Status -eq "Running"){
           Write-Output "'$ServiceName' is already started..." | Out-File $LogFile -append
           Write-Output " " | Out-File $LogFile -append
           FinalServiceStatus
}

    if ($arrService.Status -ne "Running"){
        CurrentServiceStatus
        $arrService = Start-Service $ServiceName -PassThru
        if ($arrService.Status -eq "Running"){
           Write-Output "$date - '$ServiceName' started..." | Out-File $LogFile -append
           Write-Output " " | Out-File $LogFile -append
           FinalServiceStatus
        }
        elseif ($arrService.Status -ne "Running"){
           Write-Output "Error: '$ServiceName' service could not be started..." | Out-File $LogFile -append
           Write-Output " " | Out-File $LogFile -append
           FinalServiceStatus
        }
    }
}
```